# Login with Facebook option trigger suggest to download an app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, macos, authentication

Yesterday I logged in to Airbnb with my Facebook account on my OSX. Shortly later I got a notification both on my iPhone and computer saying

"Airbnb is available to install on your iPhone"

My question is, does anyone here know how this was done? Is this a feature available to anyone who creates Facebook login?  Any advice on how this was done is well appreciated.

Sincerely 
Axel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what I was talking about. Facebook is adding a new feature which ask users if they want to get a link to the mobile app.

This is in Beta right now but you will automatically eligible for the feature if:

- You have integrated the new Facebook Login on your website. You must be using at least version 2.0 of the Graph API and Login Dialog. Send to Mobile is not available for apps which invoke the Login dialog using Graph API v1.0.
- You have integrated Facebook Login into your iOS or Android app. The "Single Sign On" switch within iOS and Android section of your app's dashboard must be set to "Yes"
- Added your iOS App Store ID and/or the Android package name under which your app is listed in Google Play to your Facebook app's dashboard.
  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/send-to-mobile

Answer (score 1):

I bet the notification is sent to you by Airbnb, right? If so, it's pretty easy to do. You give your facebook account information to Airbnb by login with facebook in there webpage. Then they just send a graph api request to facebook with your authorization access token, and you get an notification. For details you can refer to doc here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually found out that this was a new feature Facebook has in Beta right now, so it won't appear for everyone.   You can read more about here, but I think in short, if you are using Facebook login this will automatically become a feature.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/send-to-mobile