# Send Facebook notifications to users

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I wonder if anyone can offer any advice - If a user likes my page on Facebook, can I somehow trigger a notification to them to prompt them to download my app on iOS/Android? The information I'm finding doesn't seem conclusive.

Thanks!

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: @WizKid - does that still apply if the user has auth'd to our app with Facebook? I'm sure I've seen something where I signed up for a site (auth'ing with Facebook) and when I logged into Facebook after there was a notification waiting for me asking me if I'd like to download the app for said website.

Comment: They were testing a feature where you could get the web version of the login dialog to show a checkbox for the user to request to be send a download link for the app from the respective app store to their mobile – but the documentation link mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30951818/1427878 is not working any more, so it might be that they have discontinued that.

Comment: @WizKid - don't suppose you know what is happening with the feature mentioned here? Is it scrapped? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844176/login-with-facebook-option-trigger-suggest-to-download-an-app/30951818#30951818

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update people - this can be done under the right conditions. AirBnB do it for example.

If your iOS/Android app uses Facebook Authentication you can harness the Notification API but **only** if your app has Facebook Canvas enabled.

Also, to send the Notification to a particular user (authed to your app) you must use an 'app token' rather than a 'user token' as you are performing an action on behalf of the app, not one particular user (like when you publish to their feed).

Because of this and the fact to obtain this token you must expose your app ID and secret it is advisable to carry out the notification push using server-side code - not client side or in an app that can be decompiled.

The docs aren't 100% up to date as they contradict themselves a little but you can find more info here:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications